# Warping raster to new domain/resolution/projection causes data loss

Tags: raster, gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I am attempting to warp a GTiff from a lat/lon projection to a higher (~2x) resolution Polar Stereographic grid.

In the output GTiff any cells north of 64 deg lat become NaN instead of their actual values.

I am using gdalwarp thusly:

```py
  gdalwarp -t_srs 'wkt string here' -tr 5000 5000 -te -4252339.5,-5302590.0,4597660.5,2747410.25 in.tif out.tif
```

What could be causing the output raster to have the blank area?

Input extents are [-84.84, -50.19, 55.07, 79.96]. [minLon,maxLon,minLat,maxLat]

Output Coordinate system:

proj4 (+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60 +lon_0=-100 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs) .

It's standard Polar Stereographic but with Central Meridian at -100 deg and latitude of origin at 60 deg.

---

The issue was caused by the large difference in coordinate systems. (The domain was self-intersecting in one of the coord systems). It was largely solved by explicitly entering the output extent instead of having GDAL attempt to guess it.

i.e *-te -180 0 180 90* was added to the gdalwarp line.

Comment: Can you add the extents of the input geotiff?

Comment: And the target CRS? Is there a WKID (versus posting the WKT)? I'd like to try to reproduce the conversion in other software.

Comment: Input extents are [-84.84, -50.19, 55.07, 79.96]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me with a two-step-transformation:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60 +lon_0=-100 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -of GTiff D:\Download\NEU\ster-wgs84.tif D:/Download/NEU/ster-100-transformed.tif
gdalwarp -overwrite -wo SAMPLE_STEPS=1000 -t_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60 +lon_0=-100 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -tr 5000 5000 -te -4252339.5 -5302590.0 4597660.5 2747410.25 ster-100-transformed.tif out.tif
```

A reason might be that your target extent crosses the 180° line, making the extent a self-intersecting polygon in the source srs WGS84:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try  with larger number of sample steps `-wo SAMPLE_STEPS=1000`

[Reprojecting Natural Earth raster into natearth projection with gdalwarp causing black squares?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111320/reprojecting-natural-earth-raster-into-natearth-projection-with-gdalwarp-causing)

Or with lower error threshold `-et 0.01`

[gdalwarp leaves horizontal artifacts regridding from EASE-Grid (laea) to Polarstero (stere)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116465/gdalwarp-leaves-horizontal-artifacts-regridding-from-ease-grid-laea-to-polarst)