# Lat/Long Format and Conversion

Tags: qgis, convert, format

I have downloaded data in a .mif file format and I was having issues overlaying it in QGIS. I checked the attribute table and the latitude and longitude were showing as below, this is one line from the entire table:

LA_1_LATITUDE is 44.878

LO_1_LONGITUD is 243.14

Looking into the data provider they provided the following information about the Coordsys:

[image]

I tried some of the conversion suggestions but nothing has worked.  Is there a way to convert the lat and long into something that can be overlaid in QGIS or QGIS plugins. Or is there details in the clause above that would allow me to manipulate the data to get coordinates I can use.

Comment: Have you tried to create own custom projection based on provided parameters? https://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html

Comment: The best fitting EPSG code is `EPSG:53026`. Copy that to the custom CRS dialogue form, and change the parameters as given in your image. Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134239/warping-raster-to-new-domain-resolution-projection-causes-data-loss

Comment: @AndreJ  53026 is an Esri WKID, not an EPSG one.

Comment: @mkennedy I know that, but inside QGIS it is still referred to as EPSG: