# gdalwarp reprojects only a portion of the raster

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I´m trying to re-project a raster from epsg:4326 to epsg:3035 to work with European based datasets.

I have been using this command:

```
gdalwarp -srcnodata 9.95924e+36 -dstnodata 9.95924e+36 -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3035 $loc_t$temp.tiff $loc_t$name.tiff
```

This should create a re-projected tiff file. However the result seems to be that only a 6th of the raster is re-projected and the rest is simply not there.[image: 1/6th of the map]

The image shows two problems. Only the top center part of the raster is showing, with the others either missing completely or as nodata, and there is a gap at the pole.

I am not sure what is causing this as the on the fly re-projection using grass shows no problem as seen here:
[image: On the fly projection]

Lastly I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111320/reprojecting-natural-earth-raster-into-natearth-projection-with-gdalwarp-causing) post. Here the solution to a similar problem was the addition of the -wo command:

```
gdalwarp -wo SAMPLE_STEPS=1000 -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3035 $loc_t$temp.tiff $loc_t$name.tiff
```

This does not seem to help. Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That reprojection looks really bad down through Asia. What are the bounds of the source data? Which version of gdalwarp are you using? Have you tried using `-wo SAMPLE_GRID=YES`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might run into a problem with the antipodal point of the projection. If you clip your raster to the area of validity (that is Europe), it works:

```
 gdal_translate -projwin -26 75 44 28 -of GTiff bluemarble.tif bluemarble-Europe.tif
 gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3035 -of GTiff bluemarble-Europe.tif bluemarble-3035.tif
```

[image]

You might take a larger extent, but be sure to stay on the northern hemisphere:

```
 gdal_translate -projwin -180 89 180 0 -of GTiff bluemarble.tif bluemarble-Europe.tif
 gdalwarp -overwrite -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3035 -of GTiff bluemarble-Europe.tif bluemarble-3035b.tif
```

[image]

With `SAMPLE_GRID`, it even works down to 10°S:

```
 gdal_translate -projwin -180 89 180 -10 -of GTiff bluemarble.tif bluemarble-North.tif
 gdalwarp -overwrite -wo SAMPLE_GRID=YES -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3035 -of GTiff bluemarble-North.tif bluemarble-3035n.tif
```

Comment: Thank you so much AndreJ,
Since I only need continental Europe your solution works perfectly.